# How do I derive a value for a column based on another column's value?

Tags: sql, mysql-5.6

I have a `projects` table like the one below. There are two
slightly different id columns `idx` and `idy`–one `idx` can have multiple `idy`s (for
versioning).

```
  idx,     idy,         name,  use_count, usage_date
-----, -------, ------------, ----------, ----------
   x1,     x11,    x1 name 1,         10,          1
   x1,     x13,    x1 name 3,         10,          3
   x1,     x12,    x1 name 2,         10,          2
   x2,     x21,    x2 name 1,         10,          2
   x3,     x31,    x3 name 1,         10,          2
```

The goal is to consolidate the usage such that for every `idx`, the result will
have:

- a `use_count` col which is `SUM(use_count)` for same `idx`
- the latest `usage_date`
- the name corresponding to the latest usage_date

Additionally, usage_date has to be within a certain range, but this hopefully is trivial.

```
  idx,     idy,         name,  use_count, usage_date
-----, -------, ------------, ----------, ----------
   x1,     x13,    x1 name 3,         30,          3
   x2,     x21,    x2 name 1,         10,          2
   x3,     x31,    x3 name 1,         10,          2
```

So far, I've got

```
SELECT
  idx, idy, name,
  sum(use_count) as use_count,
  usage_date
FROM
  projects
WHERE
  usage_date <= 3
GROUP BY
  idx
```

..but having trouble figuring out how to derive the latest name of the project
(with id `x1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way -

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7b9fd21886bd4cf95dbe3911b912ed63)

```
select X.idx,idy,name,X.use_count,usage_date from
(
select idx,sum(use_count) as use_count
from t
group by idx
)X inner join
(
select * from t a where usage_date = (select max(usage_date) from t b where a.idx=b.idx)
)Y on X.idx=Y.idx
```

Output:

```
idx idy   name       use_count  usage_date
x1  x13   x1 name 3     30            3
x2  x21   x2 name 1     10            2
x3  x31   x3 name 1     10            2
```

Comment: `t` in your answer is in fact a UNION of selects. Is there a way I can avoid writing the relative huge statement in three places (as t is in your answer)? (I'm new to SQL)

Comment: t is a table name , you can replace t with your table name, or any statements @nabn

Comment: I get that. For an expensive subselect, it'd be nice to do it once and use it in all three places is what I'm saying.

Comment: in mysql 5.6 I think the concept of common table expression is not available, with upper version you can use a common table expression and instead of writing the huge statement in 3 times, you can define there once and use that in 3 places. @nabn